# Regex to remove a specific object from an array along with comma if it is followed to it

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I am looking for a regex to remove a specific json object from an array of objects along with the comma if it is followed to it.

JSon Array

```
[ { "id" : "id1", "value" : "value1"},
  { "id" : "id2", "value" : "value2"},
  { "id" : "id3", "value" : "value3"},
  { "id" : "id4", "value" : "value4"} ]
```

I want to remove object `{ "id" : "id3", "value" : "value3"}` from the above array. Since it has a comma (,) appended, I want to remove that as well otherwise array wont be in a json format.

Again, this is just the sample. The array might contain n number of objects. the object can come in any order , it may be at the first object, or come in middle, or the last object.

So, regex should check if there is a comma after the object , then remove object with comma else remove only object.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why would you use a regex for this?

Comment: I am building something in nifi and nifi supports regex. I have to use regex as I have no good choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `QueryRecord` processor that Apache NiFi offers. You can find more details about this processor [here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/index.html) but the general thing is this: it allows you to run a `SQL` query against a flowfile content.

So you can add a dynamic relationship to `QueryRecord` with a SQL statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE id <> 'id3'
```

This gets executed against the flowfile content and only the records whose `id` is not equal to `id3` are bundled together and sent as a flowfile to that dynamic relationship.

This approach avoids the use of RegEx which is computation expensive. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for late reply, yeah, this is what i was actually looking for. Thanks a bunch. This made my solution way better

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of a regex that uses the unique id field to find the right object:

```
\h*{[^}]+?"id3"[^}]+?},?\h*\n?(?=]?)
```

Example of it in action: https://regex101.com/r/0tRs09/2/

If you need to use a capture group, just put parenthesis around the whole thing.

Comment: This works! But same expression is not a valid java regular expression. Do we know the equivalent java regular expression?